# How can jq reference a property with a non-identifier character in the name (like "@")?

Tags: json, key, jq

It seems unlikely this hasn't been asked, but I can not find it anywhere.

I am trying to filter response from elasticsearch and need to reference the `@timestamp` field. However, `jq` uses `@` to specify [formatters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) and I find nothing in documentation about how to escape the `@` character.

```
$ jq '.hits.hits[] | ._source.@timestamp' < debug.response.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.hits.hits[] | ._source.@timestamp
jq: 1 compile error
```

Comment: Could you provide a **minimal** example of the JSON in `debug.response.json`, so people can try out their answers before posting them?

Comment: Use double-quotes around the field name to handle special characters, e.g. `."@timestamp"`. Documented [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar), tested [here](https://jqplay.org/s/eLJ2IearlZ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [generic object index](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#GenericObjectIndex:.[%3Cstring%3E]) syntax, like:

```
.hits.hits[]._source["@timestamp"]
```

Comment: Yup, I finally just got `jq` working locally so I could try this on spec (couldn't immediately find it in the docs) and this syntax worked fine. But you'd already posted by the time I got back. :-)

Comment: I ended up looking at the lexer source and finding out you can use `.source."@timestamp"`, but totally failed to find either solution in the documentation. Thanks for the solution and link!